# Getting the max value in a grouped query from MySQL

Tags: mysql, grouping

Sorry but i'm stucking at this given table *tbl_inventar*:

| artikelID | istAnzahl | sollAnzahl | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 2022-10-23 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2022-10-25 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 2022-10-23 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-10-24 |

I would like to get the *artikelID* and the value of *istAnzahl* associated with the *max(date)*.

Like this:

| artikelID | istAnzahl | sollAnzahl | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2022-10-25 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-10-24 |

I've tried the following, but somehow I'm just getting desperate.

```
Select
  tbl_inventar.artikelID,
  tbl_inventar.istAnzahl,
  tbl_inventar.sollAnzahl,
  Max(tbl_inventar.date) As Max_date
From
  tbl_inventar
Group By
  tbl_inventar.artikelID
```

But this doesn't give the associated values for *istAnzahl*

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() in CTE.

Comment: Does `(artikelID,date)` is defined as UNIQUE in the table structure?

Comment: @Akina no it is not. otherwise there could not be more than one artikelID (with different values ​​for istAnzahl and date)

Comment: *no it is not* If so then the situation when 2 separate rows contains the same values for `artikelID` and `date` columns (and the value in `date` is maximal over this `artikelID`), but with different values in `istAnzahl` column. What one value of those two must be returned for `istAnzahl`? *otherwise there could not be more than one artikelID* No, separate columns values (`istAnzahl` only or `date` only) may have duplicates - but not their values pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On older MySQL version which do not support windows function you could use a subquery to get the max date per each artikelID and you need to add on the join condition. Based on *there could not be more than one artikelID (with different values ​​for istAnzahl and date)* with the following query you will alyways get the latest record based on date:

```
select t.artikelID,
       t.istAnzahl,
       t.sollAnzahl,
       t.`date`
from test t
inner join (select artikelID , max(`date`) as max_date
            from test
            group by artikelID
          ) as max_dt on max_dt.artikelID=t.artikelID and max_dt.max_date=t.`date`;
```

On MySQL versions which do support windows function :

```
select artikelID,
       istAnzahl,
       sollAnzahl,
       `date`
from (select *, row_number() over(partition by artikelID order by `date` desc ) as max_dt
      from test
    ) tbl 
where tbl.max_dt=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Ej4sxL4O

Comment: Using the same name for aggregated column allows to simplify the join till NATURAL. Also it makes no sense to select date from the subquery. https://dbfiddle.uk/zDCkJFY5